# Why aren't my modifications to xkb working?

Tags: xorg, kde, keyboard-layout, internationalization, xkb

## Short version

Currently, `AltGr`+`-` produces ¥. I wish for it to produce an en-dash. In `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`, I replaced all occurances of "yen" with "endash" and restarted, but this made no difference.

For the record:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     us
variant:    altgr-intl
options:    lv3:ralt_switch_multikey,numpad:pc
```

---

## Longer version

I intially started by looking in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`, which contains a section marked `xkb_symbols "altgr-intl" {`. This section contains `include "us(intl)"` and `include "level3(ralt_switch)"`, and no mention of `AE11` (which is the keycode for `-`).

The section marked `xkb_symbols "intl" {` contains `key <AE11> { [ minus, underscore, yen, dead_belowdot ] };`, and so I modified the `yen` here in the AltGr position to `endash`. I restarted and this made no difference, so I did the brute force method as above (then restarted).

## More troubleshooting

If I set `setxkbmap -layout us -variant mac`, `AltGr`+`-` produces an en-dash as expected (and as defined in the `xkb_symbols "mac" {` section).

I also tried swapping `q` and `w` in the `xkb_symbols "basic" {` and `xkb_symbols "intl" {` sections, but this change did not do anything after restarting. I also tried `setxkbmap -layout us` to select the `basic` layout, but this also had no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to delete the cached xkb configurations at `/var/lib/xkb/*.xkm`, then restart.

Some have complained that they were unable to use their keyboard "in X next time it was started (but only that once)", although I had no problem like this at all.

Thanks to bcooksley at the KDE forums for [providing the answer](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=117032#p290235).