# Mapping changes to keyboard layout not taking effect

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I wanted to modify several layouts to make them phonetic (асдф and ასდფ where asdf are), and add some missing letters in the Georgian keyboard.

I checked the following threads, among others:

http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_keyboard_tools.html

https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/index.html

I modified and saved the corresponding files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` but even after restarting the layouts worked just the same. I checked the files and they had changed.

Say I changed

```
key <AC05> {[0x010010d2,G,0x010010f9]};
```

to

```
key <AC05> {[0x010010d2,Georgian_ghan,0x010010f9]};
```

but <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> still produced G. Also, the third and fourth positions (for altgr and altgr+shift) never work at all.

Then I found these threads:

[Why aren't my modifications to xkb working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330885/why-arent-my-modifications-to-xkb-working)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1589744

[us keyboard not working in 14.04 after removing *.xkm files from /var/lib/xkb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611604/us-keyboard-not-working-in-14-04-after-removing-xkm-files-from-var-lib-xkb)

And went to `/var/lib/xkb` only to find it was empty except for a readmefile, that I moved to another location to check if it'd work, to no avail.

I've also tried to make new layouts from scratch, copying the code form other files, but it doesn't work.

I'm at a loss, I don't know what else to do to be able to have the layouts I need. I've had linux and lubuntu for only a few months and this issue has consumed already lots of hours of my time only to somehow being able to change a couple of keys of the Russian keyboard.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: My Georgian keyboard is named "Georgiano - kbd (m17n)", it has R under  Shift+R. I changed Georgian_ghan with 0x010010e6 and restarted the computer, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If that was a comment on my answer, you should have submitted it as a comment on my answer. I assumed you were talking about the Georgian XKB keyboard layout, not any IBus input method, and I suppose that you can't modify the input method by editing the XKB symbols file. I don't know how to modify an input method, but if you seek help with that, you'd better clarify it by editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

XKB does not recognize all character names, and probably it doesn't understand `Georgian_ghan`. Try `0x010010e6` instead.

(ღ is also available with the Georgian layout through <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.)